# set min - max values drupal date_popup timepicker

Tags: 7, datetime

Is it possible to set the minimum and maximum values of the timepicker in a date_popup field? I use this code for the field, but something like 'minTime' is not working.

```
  $form['fetch_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#description' => t('Datum waarop u uw bestelling wil ophalen.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Afhaal Datum',
    '#datepicker_options' => array(
      'minDate' => 0,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: You many find help from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808915/jquery-ui-set-mintime-on-timepicker-based-on-other-timepicker-value)

Answer (score 0):

You may find this one helpful.

[Datepicker: minDate and maxDate](https://www.drupal.org/node/1551094#comment-7343024)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_state['view']->name) {
  case 'my_view_name':
    // the Date object works only with this date format:
    $datemask = 'Y-m-d'; 
    $form['field_date_value']['min']['#default_value'] = date($datemask, time()-30*86400);
    $form['field_date_value']['max']['#default_value'] = date($datemask);
    break;

    $datemask = 'd/m/Y';
    $form['field_date_value']['min']['#date_format'] = $datemask;
    $form['field_date_value']['max']['#date_format'] = $datemask;
  }
}
```